# Error 1069: The service did not start due to logon failure? (tried everything)

Tags: permissions, service-accounts

I'm in the middle of a deployment at my work, and I'm at my wits end with this error. None of the new services are starting, on either of the new servers, with the service account name/password. They work fine on the old servers, and they start fine with my domain admin account user.

The service has log on as service rights, is part of the local admins group, and has full permissions to the folders where the service exe files are. I was able to log into the server with the service account user and password. I also checked and the service account isn't locked in AD.

I've tried switching from domain/user to user@domain, re-copying/pasting the user/password into the service logon manually, removing and re-adding the account in the log on as service policy, removed and re-added the account in the log on as service policy, removed and re-added user account to the folder permissions,

I've literally checked everything. I don't get why this isn't working.

Comment: The second error in the event log tells me it's not part of the log on as service policy, even though it is, and I've removed and re-added it multiple times.
I also just did a gpupdate /force and rebooted.

Comment: So, I found the issue. I looked up in the list of local policies window and the account was also entered in the DENY log on as service section, and since deny trumps allow, that's why it was being denied. I removed that, and the services are starting up normally now.

Does Windows add an account into the deny section on it's own for any reason? I would have been the only one that would have put that in manually, and I 100% did not do that.

Comment: You sir are a life saver!
You should answer your own question, this would probably help a lot more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I looked up in the list of local policies window and the account was also entered in the DENY log on as service section, and since deny trumps allow, that's why it was being denied. I removed that, and the services are starting up normally now. Does Windows add an account into the deny section on it's own for any reason? I would have been the only one that would have put that in manually, and I 100% did not do that.